# Android Phonegap App - How to send notifications

Tags: android, cordova

Could anyone possibly offer some advice on how to setup Status bar notifications in Android?

My skillset is all based around design/front-end dev (hence using phonegap) so I'm a beginner with Eclipse.

I have read this tutorial - http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-create-status-bar-notifications.html and have pasted the code into the activity area of my Android Manifest file.  But I don't quite understand how it will work.  If I compile this now as an APK and install it on a phone -- is it now ready to receive notifications?  If so how do I send them, and where do I type the sending code?

Hopefully it's fairly simple as my boss is hoping that I'll have it completed before christmas!

Cheers for your help.
All the best
Paul

Answer (score 3):

You want status bar notification? If yes...you are lucky...here's a plugin which I already created for phonegap. Look around for how to embed the external plugin in android.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

Comment: Cheers Ashwarya - This looks great - though i'd also need a method to push data to these notifications from an external server - any ideas on this - cheers for your help.  Paul

Comment: Hey paul. Check this link. You will find all details on integrating push notification from external server. It gives the details of the service which is absolutely free for around 200000 notifications per month. and after which you would have to pay. http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/37159628/Notifications

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) you can find better explanation with source codes about notifications.

Notification can be a reaction on some event. For instance, you can develop a simple application with one button. When you press this button a notification will be displayed in the status bar.

About the development. You should install Android SDK, create an emulator of the device. Also it is very useful to install Android ADT - this is a pluging for Eclipse to help to develop Android applications. After that when you build an application it will be automatically installed on the emulator.

Here is the code how to make a simple notification:

```
package your.package
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AcNotificationTestMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final int SEND_ID = 1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button mBtnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mBtnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Log.v("","OnClick...");
        // Create an object of Notification manager 
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int icon = android.R.drawable.sym_action_email; // icon from resources
        CharSequence tickerText = "New Notification";   // ticker-text
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
        Context context = getApplicationContext();      // application Context
        CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";  // expanded message title
        CharSequence contentText = "Click me!";         // expanded message text

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AcNotificationTestMain.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        // the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the configurations above
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);


        mNotificationManager.notify(SEND_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

And layout file:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="@string/AcNotificationTest_BtnSendNotificationText" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - I still dont quite understand how i send a notification to a user that has the app installed?  Do we need to send an updated version of the app out every time we want to send a new notification?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: also - I have got the android sdk and emulator installed.  I just dont know where i place the code mentioned in the tutorial.  do i create a new java file or does it all go in the manifest?  sorry this is probably all very basic...  Once this service is setup in the app - how do I send a new message?  Thanks very much for your help by the way!

Comment: Hi Yury,  I have a phonegap app already setup.  It is yet to go into the marketplace - but we want to have notifications setup so we can send out notifications of new products/sales etc.  But i'm just struggling to understand how the whole process works - once setup - how do i send a message out?  Thanks for all your help..

Comment: Ok, I think that we did not understand each other. Let me clarify. You've developed an application using Phonegap. Now you want to embed in this application an ability to receive information from your company about new promotions. And you want to display this information as a status bar notification?

Comment: Yury - thanks so much for the above - one last question is - do I add this to my current phonegap app as a separate java file within the src folder? 
Also - once this is compiled as an apk within my music app - how do I send the notication message to peoples phones?  This is the bit i'm struggling to understand.
Cheers though - your a legend - if you were around i'd buy you a beer!

Comment: sorry Yury - yes you are correct - I have developed a Phonegap app to promote music - its not yet live - but i want to embed the ability to receive status bar notifications - does this make things more complex?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6091/discussion-between-paul-and-yury)